# Triggered Send Data Extension used for Journey Entry Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, triggered-send

I'm looking to use a Triggered Send Data Extension as the Entry Data Extension for a Journey.

So a Triggered Send Email will be sent, then on a schedule the Triggered Send Data Extension will be evaluated for new records to enter the Journey.

Has anyone done this before? Do you see any issues with this approach?

Comment: How are you firing the triggered send?

Answer (score 1):

The application will not prevent you from selecting a Triggered Send-Templated data extension as your entry source as it is simply a sendable data extension. I don't see any system-related issues that would occur using a setup as you have described.

However, depending on the use case it could work, or querying into another data extension may be better suited. For instance, if you want to send a series of emails to those that were sent a triggered send, then this setup could work. However, a potential downside to this setup is what if a triggered send errored and caused queuing? You now expected those subscribers that were supposed to be sent a triggered send but didn't get it, then the following emails may not make sense to the subscriber.